# Use TinyMCE with EditorFor field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, tinymce, editorfor

Currently I use MVC model and EditorFor field with Accordion objects.

```
<div id="accordionSub0">
@{
    int count = 0;

    foreach(var item in @Model.ResolutionsList)
    {
        string textBoxID = "RichTextBox" + count;
        string accordionSub = "accordionSub" + count;
        var result = @Model.ResolutionsList[count].Resolutions;
            <h3><a href="#">Step @count</a></h3>
            <div id="@textBoxID" class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResolutionsList[count].Resolutions,
                new
                {
                    style = "width:" + 100 + "%; height:" + 5 + "em;"
                })
            </div>

        count++;
    }
}
</div>
```

Model:

```
public partial class InformationDataModel
{
    public int RID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string InfoType { get; set; }

    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string Symptoms { get; set; }
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string Cause { get; set; }
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string Resolution { get; set; }
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string Resolution2 { get; set; }
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string References { get; set; }

    public List<InformationResolutionsDataModel> ResolutionsList { get; set; }

    public string IssuedDate { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string RelevantUsers { get; set; }
    public string TagNames { get; set; }
}

public partial class InformationResolutionsDataModel
{
    public int RID { get; set; }

    public int ResolutionID { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string Resolutions { get; set; }

    public string IssuedDate { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResolutionsList[count].Resolutions`,

They bring value into textarea, but they do not show with TinyMCE.

So, I check view source in website that loaded.

They automatically generate inside.

```
$('#ResolutionsList[0].Resolutions').tinymce({
```

but text area side.

```
textarea Length="22681" cols="20" id="ResolutionsList_0__Resolutions" name="ResolutionsList[0].Resolutions" rows="2"
```

as u can see the id is not correctly generate normal MVC case.

```
$('#References').tinymce({
...
textarea Length="99" cols="20" id="References" name="References" rows="2"
```

then correctly generated.

Please give me some tips how can I control tinyMCE ids. thanks.

Ps. Here is TinyMCE_JQuery_Full.cshtml

```
$('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)').tinymce({
```

Comment: Please post the code for the tinymce_jquery_full partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your partial view, use `ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId` instead of `ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName`:

```
$('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)').tinymce({
   // ...
})
```